# What is the intuition behind the expected value in orginal GAN papers objective function?

Tags: neural-networks, expected-value, loss-functions, gan

I know how Generative Adversarial Network(GAN) works but it became a daunting task to grasp the non mathematical intuition behind the expected value in the objective function

$L_D = - \left[\; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}[log \; D(x)] + \; \mathbb{E}_{z \sim p_{z}}[log \; (1 - D(G(z)))] \right]$

After searching I found [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/13038/39) where the author explains the mathematical reasoning for the expected value. I understood most of what he had written but got stuck at this,

> Finally, D(x) represents the probability with which D thinks that x belongs to pdata. By writing the cross-entropy formula we get:
>
> $H(y, D(x)) = \mathbb{E}_y[-log \; D(x)] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{ \; y_i \; log(D(x_i))}$

- Is $D(x)$ here considered as a probability distribution?
- What is the intuition behind the expected value in it?

I am aware that we use expected value to find the mean of a distribution. I am guessing when we pass real images to discriminator we get different mean of distribution when comparing to the fake images. This difference in mean difference is significant for GAN learning!?

In my knowledge expected value is written as

$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i p_i$

then how are we deriving

$\mathbb{E}_y[-log \; D(x)]$

from

$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{ \; y_i \; log(D(x_i))}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is $D(x)$ here considered as a probability distribution?

Yes. In fact, it is the probability of label or class given an input feature vector or image, denoted as $p(c|\mathbf{x})$. Here are a few resources to better understand this:

- [the relationship between maximizing the likelihood and minimizing the cross-entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364216/the-relationship-between-maximizing-the-likelihood-and-minimizing-the-cross-entr)
- [Machine Learning: Negative Log Likelihood vs Cross-Entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468818/machine-learning-negative-log-likelihood-vs-cross-entropy)
- This is my favorite: [Why the logistic function? A tutorial discussion on probabilities and neural networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.476.1842&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Michael I. Jordan, 1995

> What is the intuition behind the expected value in it?

Unfortunately, in my opinion, the notation is a bit misleading. In general, the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Definition) between two probability distributions $p$ and $q$ with the same support $\mathcal{X}$ is:

$$
H(p,q) = -\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\log{q(x)}] = -\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x) \log{q(x)} \tag{1} \label{eq1}
$$

This means that the expression:

$$
-\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{ \; y_i \; log(D(x_i))} \tag{2} \label{eq2}
$$

Is just the cross entropy multiplied by the scalar $\frac{1}{N}$. I think this notation is misused because in the context of classification, both distributions $p$ and $q$ are discrete, and so the cross entropy is just a summation. Instead, I think the multiplication by $\frac{1}{N}$ is used to show that expression in \ref{eq2} is an approximation of the expectation in equation \ref{eq1} as the sample mean. However, as I said, all distributions are discrete, so the multiplication by $\frac{1}{N}$ is unnecessary. Also, since we want to minimize the cross entropy with respect to $q$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/505162/296197) and the links above for why), then it does not make a difference whether we multiply the cross entropy by $\frac{1}{N}$ or not.

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that although the scalar $\frac{1}{N}$ does not serve a theoretical purpose, it serves a practical one. The scalar $\frac{1}{N}$ is used to normalize the negative log-likelihood (cross entropy) function to make its gradients smaller, and therefore allows larger step sizes to be chosen if an iterative optimization procedure, such as gradient descent, is used to minimize the cross entropy function. These larger step sizes are desirable because if [backtracking line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search) is used to find the optimal step size, then it will be easier/quicker to find this optimal step size if it is larger.

For example, consider the gradient descent update rule:
$$
\theta_{k+1} \leftarrow \theta_{k} - \alpha \cdot \nabla_{\theta} f(x;\theta)
$$
Where $\alpha$ is the step size and $f(x;\theta)$ is some function parameterized by $\theta$. Suppose that $f$ was replaced with the expression in $\ref{eq2}$. Also, notice that in $\ref{eq2}$, if the factor $\frac{1}{N}$ was not there, then as $N$ increases, the value of the summation will also increase. The gradient of this summation would also be a function of $N$, such that as $N$ increases, the gradient increases in value too. This would mean that the steo size $\alpha$ would need to be smaller in order to achieve the same overall step in $\theta$ according to the gradient descent update rule.

However, if we multiply this summation by the factor $\frac{1}{N}$, then the gradient of the summation will also be a function of $\frac{1}{N}$, such that if $N$ increases, then the gradient may not increase as much as before. This will help keep gradients small such that the step size $\alpha$ does not need to be as small to achieve the same overall step according to the gradient descent rule.

As further motivation for the use of $\frac{1}{N}$, suppose that we start with $\theta_0=1$ and we know that the optimal $\theta$ is $\theta^*=0$. Also, suppose that $N$ is larger (e.g. $N=1,000$). Without $\frac{1}{N}$, the term $\nabla_{\theta} f(x;\theta)$ in the gradient descent update rule would be very large, and if $\alpha\approx 0.05$, then the new value of $\theta$ after only 1 iteration would be extremely small (even negative), clearly overshooting our target of $\theta^*=0$. If we re-introduce $\frac{1}{N}$ while keeping $\alpha$ the same, then the value of $\theta$ after 1 iteration will still be smaller, but not as much as before.

Comment: Agreed! The notation in the paper is not very clear. I didn't knew if $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim pdata(x)}[\log D(x)]$ should be read as "The expected value of 'x' given it comes from p(x) times $\log D(x)$" or "the expected value of $\log D(x)$ when x comes from p(x)". I assume its the latter?