# Ways to Reduce False Positive or False Negatives in Binary Classification (0,1)

Tags: classification, python, unbalanced-classes

I am working on a task in which I need to classify binary labels 0 and 1 properly (as close to perfection as possible). My final dataset (ready for classification) has input data with 141 features and binary labels. The original data is a time-series data generated using inductive sensor and the features are extracted from it using Short Time Fourier Transform. Moreover, the dataset is *highly *imbalanced**, total number of label 0 is 39263 whereas that of label 1 is 71 ( with 39334 total number of samples).

I have developed a Neural Network classification model using PyTorch. I have used the following chunk of code in order to split the data into Train, Test and Validation datasets.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1 - train_ratio, stratify=y, shuffle=True)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=test_ratio/(test_ratio + validation_ratio), stratify=y_test)
```

In order to handle class imbalance issue, I have generated class weights using sklearn tool, assigned the weights to each sample and then passed the weights as an argument to CrossEntropy Loss Function. Class weight for label 0 is 0.50090416 whereas that for label 1 is 277.

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.unique(y), y=y)
class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float)
sample_weights = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight(class_weight= {0:0.50090416, 1:277}, y= y, indices=None)
```

Following is my model:

```
# number of features (len of X cols)
input_dim = 141
# number of hidden layers
hidden_layers = 5
# number of classes (unique of y)
output_dim = 2
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_layers)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_layers, output_dim)
        self.drop_layer = nn.Dropout(p=0.25)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.drop_layer(x)
        hidden = self.linear1(x)
        relu = self.relu(hidden)
        x = self.drop_layer(x)
        output = self.linear2(relu)
        return output

clf = Network()
```

And the loss function and optimizer has been defined as follows:

```
criterion_weighted = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights, reduction='mean')
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(clf.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.01)
```

Training, validation and testing phases are represented by the following code snippet:

```
batch size = 20
epoch = 10
t_accuracy_gain = []
accuracy_gain = []
for epoch in range(epochs):

    # Training
    training_loss = 0
    total, total_t = 0, 0
    for train_input, train_labels in trainloader:
        # set optimizer to zero grad to remove previous epoch gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = clf(train_input)
        loss = criterion_weighted(y_pred, train_labels)
        loss.backward()
        # optimize
        optimizer.step()
        training_loss += loss.item()
        y_pred = torch.nn.functional.softmax(y_pred, dim=1)
        for i, p in enumerate(y_pred):
            if train_labels[i] == torch.max(p.data, 0)[1]:
                total_t = total_t+1

    accuracy_t = total_t/train_size
    t_accuracy_gain.append(accuracy_t)

    # Validating
    valid_loss = 0.0
    for val_inputs, val_labels in valloader:
        # Forward Pass
        y_pred_val = clf(val_inputs)
        # Find the Loss
        loss = criterion_weighted(y_pred_val, val_labels)
        # Calculate Loss
        valid_loss += loss.item()
        y_pred_val = torch.nn.functional.softmax(y_pred_val, dim=1)
        for i, p in enumerate(y_pred_val):
            if val_labels[i] == torch.max(p.data, 0)[1]:
                total = total+1

    accuracy = total/val_size
    accuracy_gain.append(accuracy)

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} \t\t Training Loss: { training_loss/len(trainloader)} \t\t Validation Loss: { valid_loss/len(valloader)}')
    print(accuracy_t, accuracy)

    epoch += 1

# Testing

test = []
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    for i, X in enumerate(X_test):
        y_pred = clf(X)
        if y_pred.argmax().item() == y_test[i]:
            correct += 1
        test.append(y_pred.argmax().item())
print(f'{correct} out of {y_test.shape[0]} is correct : {correct/y_test.shape[0]*100}%')
print(np.unique(test, return_counts=True))
print(test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, test))
print('Precision: %.16f' % precision_score(y_test, test))
print('Recall: %.16f' % recall_score(y_test, test))
print('F1_score: %.16f' % f1_score(y_test, test))
```

Now, the results I am obtaining are very frustrating. Although I am assigning weights to my classes, still the model is unable to classify the minority class. The following are the results obtained after 10 epochs:

```
Epoch 1          Training Loss: 0.18776317898373482          Validation Loss: 0.15920198694881746
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 2          Training Loss: 0.15280305894249577          Validation Loss: 0.15878191357952054
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 3          Training Loss: 0.14959193905152507          Validation Loss: 0.15635720060791
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 4          Training Loss: 0.14844961922426345          Validation Loss: 0.15760730873730222
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 5          Training Loss: 0.14479931982518252          Validation Loss: 0.15391030547729992
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 6          Training Loss: 0.14200111128010992          Validation Loss: 0.15406650864219262
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 7          Training Loss: 0.13820280621238684          Validation Loss: 0.15289437643931073
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 8          Training Loss: 0.13983591395540762          Validation Loss: 0.15828328180616186
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 9          Training Loss: 0.13601937021113047          Validation Loss: 0.15396189160518728
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
Epoch 10         Training Loss: 0.1354785456634679       Validation Loss: 0.15328112466860624
0.9982033898305085 0.998135593220339
3927 out of 3934 is correct : 99.8220640569395%
```

[image]

As can be observed from the above metrics, the model is classifying all the 0 labels properly, but 1 labels have been incorrectly classified as *false negatives*.

After this, I randomly oversampled the training and validation dataset using SMOTE technique and the following are the results that I have obtained:

```
Epoch 1          Training Loss: 0.19352763494530437          Validation Loss: 1.5280835092738145
0.9684348150915204 0.5
Epoch 2          Training Loss: 0.26620812748063905          Validation Loss: 1.5480152127951232
0.928753353482528 0.5
Epoch 3          Training Loss: 0.2296104698174701       Validation Loss: 1.5715507436132592
0.9466159540870037 0.5
Epoch 4          Training Loss: 0.21165923436025255          Validation Loss: 1.585304197290808
0.9547661901042551 0.5
Epoch 5          Training Loss: 0.1981869825486138       Validation Loss: 1.596927644055596
0.9594186164974361 0.5
Epoch 6          Training Loss: 0.19129694016564935          Validation Loss: 1.6035434622475673
0.9616769110605494 0.5
Epoch 7          Training Loss: 0.188139278968521        Validation Loss: 1.6061198817904412
0.9625428736373824 0.5
Epoch 8          Training Loss: 0.18814285206584758          Validation Loss: 1.605698257425392
0.9628145481712908 0.5
Epoch 9          Training Loss: 0.18444137671465885          Validation Loss: 1.6085442355272623
0.9639521852820321 0.5
Epoch 10         Training Loss: 0.181928029220001        Validation Loss: 1.6101362825085128
0.9645294936665875 0.5
7 out of 3934 is correct : 0.1779359430604982%
```

[image]

In this scenario, the model is able to classify all the 1s perfectly but is unable to classify 0s. And this should also be noticed that the validation loss is much higher than the training loss which may mean that the model is overfitting in the training phase.

Without sampling, the model is predicting the minority class as false negatives, whereas with sampling, the model is predicting the majority class as false positives. As a newbie in this field, I fail to understand how to resolve this error. Can anybody help?

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. What is the human level performance here? 2. Can you obtain more data? 3. Avoid accuracy as a metric in the case of imbalanced data. If you *have* to use something that dichotomises your outcome I would suggest using the F1 score at first instance but realistically using a proper metric like the Brier score is preferable.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by human level performance? If I understand correctly, I labelled the data on my own by digging into raw data as I have some idea of how the useful pattern should look like. 2. At this stage, I am unable to generate more data. 3. I am definietly not looking into accuracy as an evaluation metric, I am checking the recall and F1 score. However, I will for sure look into Brier score.

Comment: Can this be a possibility that I need to generate correct labels or correct my already existing labels?

Comment: If human level performance is better than this then we need to make more "model". i.e. bigger/more appropriate architecture, better/more features, etc. You say "*I labelled the data on my own by digging into raw data*" is that information visible to the model or you expect it to find it by itself? Maybe it is too obscure to discover without a huge model.

Comment: I just expect my model to learn the pattern on its own. Plus, my data is very noisy and I am not hundred percet confident about the labels. This is the reason why I have been suggested to correct my data or labels. Honestly, as a rookie, I do not exactly know how to do it. I believe that my issue is data level not model level. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Having noiseless labels is very important indeed and I would focus on that first as you say. What I am saying is that after the labels are ensured to be almost noiseless, it makes sense to help the model become more expressive if it cannot match human level performance.

Comment: 1. How can I make the label noiseless? (ideas needed)
2. How can I make the model more expressive?

Comment: 1. Get more annotators/get more expertise in labelling the data. 2. More layers, parameters, etc. It depends on the task but realistically look at papers working with similar data as you and see if they have architectural ideas that can also be used here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141483/discussion-between-aisha-nasir-and-usr11852).

Comment: One more thing, my clusters are inseparable (as observed by K-means and DBSCAN Clustering algorithms) and this can be reason why my model is unable to distinguish the labels. What can be done in this regard?

Comment: Inseparable clusters are usually a bad sign. We don't need a clustering algorithm to tell us that.

Comment: So, what can be done in this regard?

Comment: Get a representation (i.e. model) that classes are separable. See the tread here for a nice discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215696/